# Pull the list of Countries in Microsoft AD using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to pull the list of all the countries present in the Drop Down in Microsoft AD using powershell. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?
We are not here to write code for you.
Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Since the Active Directory property type for the attribute "language" for the object class "user" is "string", you could pretty much write there what ever you want. The list of countries you'll see in Active Directories Users and Computers depends on your systems locale settings.

Comment: @Paxz : I just needed some help. I tried with all the AD Powershell commands. This is a site for help and queries I understand that. If you cant help then please let other help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just the built-in list of countries recognised by Windows.  One way to get them is like this:

```
[CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::SpecificCultures) |
    ForEach-Object {
        (New-Object System.Globalization.RegionInfo $_.Name).EnglishName
    } | Select-Object -Unique | Sort-Object
```

I have a feeling there may be a simpler way, but this works, and gives a list like this:

```
Afghanistan
Åland Islands
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
...
```

Comment: This! Active Directory doesn't store a list of countries, it's the `dsa.msc` console that generates that list, likely from the same underlying API as `[CultureInfo]::GetCultures()`

Comment: @boxdog  Thanks a lot